# web2py SQLFORM.grid () get field values on process

Tags: sql, forms, grid, web2py

on my edit/add page for SQLFORM.grid I would like to get the values of some fields on process. In case this value in combination with another field  (userid) already exists user has to be notified about it.

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want creation to fail in this case (i.e., make it part of the validation), or do you want to allow the new record but simply display a notification to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define the validator for one of the fields so it doesn't allow duplicates when the other field is also a duplicate, and then let the standard form validation process handle everything:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('userid', 'reference auth_user'),
    Field('otherfield',
          requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.mytable.userid == request.vars.userid),
                                'mytable.otherfield')))
```

Whenever a form is submitted, the `IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator will return an error if the value of "otherfield" is duplicated among the set of records where "userid" is also duplicated.

Comment: solved with db.shifts.sh_code.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.shifts.sh_organisation == org),'shifts.sh_code') in my controller